# 'and' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file

how to check the existence of directory or file names with spaces

```
@echo off
if not exist "C:\"Documents and Settings"\box\putty\file"
( 
echo hello
)
pause
```

error:

```
'and' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
hello
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the other quotes, paths are surrounded by only 1 set of quotes (`""`)

```
@echo off
if not exist "C:\Documents and Settings\box\putty\file" ( 
echo hello
)
pause
```

Make sure there's a space between `" (`

Comment: no it doesn't even gets inside the if statement without quotes

Comment: Paths are only encased in one set of quotes, the problem is your script has a syntax error somehere. **Edit**, fixed it, batch files are picky with spaces.